# puppeteer: wait N seconds before continuing to the next line

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer, browser-testing

In *puppeteer* I would like to wait a defined time before going to the next line of code.

I've tried to put a `setTimeout` in an evaluate function but it seems to be simply ignored

```
console.log('before waiting');
await page.evaluate(async() => {
  setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('waiting');
  }, 4000)
});
console.log('after waiting');
```

This code don't wait and just write *before waiting* and *after waiting*

Do you know how to do this?

Comment: await page.evaluate(async() => {
    setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('waiting');
}, 4000);}); your code is not right , above is the right

Answer (score 247, accepted):

You can use a little promise function,

```
function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve, time)
   });
}
```

Then, call it whenever you want a delay.

```
console.log('before waiting');
await delay(4000);
console.log('after waiting');
```

If you must use puppeteer use the builtin waitForTimeout function.

```
await page.waitForTimeout(4000)
```

If you still want to use page.evaluate, resolve it after 4 seconds. You are not resolving anything.

```
await page.evaluate(async() => {
    await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
           setTimeout(resolve, 1000)
    });
});
```

But I guess you can simply use the first two examples.

Comment: are you sure this is working ? You can't use delay() inside page.evaluate() it does not belongs to its context.

Comment: I am pretty sure the delay function and the page.evaluate are different examples.

Comment: `waitFor` is deprecated, use `waitForTimeout` instead.

Comment: it's smark. But I can't figure out why "function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve, time)
   });
}" works...

Comment: `waitForTimeout` is deprecated too. Best to find a better predicate to block on: `waitForFunction`, `waitForNetworkIdle`, `waitForResponse`, `waitForSelector`, etc.

Answer (score 125):

I've been using:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(3000);
```

Where 3000 is Milliseconds
And that seems to be working for me.

Comment: waitfor() has been depricated. use page.waitForTimeout(1000) instead

Comment: `page.waitForTimeout()` is now obsolete.
Replace with `new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, milliseconds));`

Answer (score 63):

You can use one of the following options to **wait for one second**:

```
await page.waitFor(1000);
await frame.waitFor(1000);
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
```

Alternatively, there are many Puppeteer functions that include a built-in `delay` option, which may come in handy for waiting between certain events:

```
// Click Delay
// Time to wait between mousedown and mouseup in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.

await page.click('#example', {delay: 1000});
await frame.click('#example', {delay: 1000});
await elementHandle.click({delay: 1000});
await page.mouse.click(0, 0, {delay: 1000});

// Type Delay
// Time to wait between key presses in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.

await page.type('#example', 'Hello, world!', {delay: 1000});
await frame.type('#example', 'Hello, world!', {delay: 1000});
await elementHandle.type('Hello, world!', {delay: 1000});
await page.keyboard.type('Hello, world!', {delay: 1000});

// Press Delay
// Time to wait between keydown and keyup in milliseconds. Defaults to 0.

await elementHandle.press('Backspace', {delay: 1000});
await page.keyboard.press('Backspace', {delay: 1000});
```

Comment: waitFor is deprecated and will be removed. The new function is waitForTimeout
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214

Comment: waitForTimeout is also deprecated

Comment: Just addin to the discussion. If anyone hits problems of not getting elements, delay is one the best of options to keep the automation flow smooth and avoid errors (besides try and catch and else, of course)

Answer (score 27):

[page.waitFor](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) has now been deprecated.

[page.waitForTimeout](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfortimeoutmilliseconds) is now advised to pause script execution for the given number of milliseconds before continuing:

```
await page.waitForTimeout(1000)
```

Comment: update docs link please

Answer (score 9):

Other answers have shown how to sleep, but now that `page.waitForTimeout` is [finally deprecated in 16.1.1](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v16.1.1) and was [removed in 22.0.0](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/puppeteer-core-v22.0.0), I figure I'd add the answer I've wanted to add for awhile:

Don't sleep! It causes a race condition that disrupts the event-driven nature of Puppeteer, introducing unnecessary brittleness. There's almost always a better predicate to wait on, either explicitly or using the [Locator](https://pptr.dev/guides/locators/) API:

- Are you waiting for a CSS selector, aria label, text or XPath to appear? Try `waitForSelector` (optionally with the appropriate [built-in selector](https://pptr.dev/guides/query-selectors#built-in-selectors)).
- Are you waiting for a navigation? Try `waitForNavigation` or adjust the `waitUntil` option on `goto`.
- Are you waiting for a network event or state? Try `waitForRequest`, `waitForResponse` or `waitForNetworkIdle`.
- Are you waiting for a popup? Try [promisifying `page.on("dialog", ...`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587534/6243352).
- Are you waiting for some arbitrary predicate, like a minimum number of child elements to appear? Try `waitForFunction`.
- Something else? Run an `evaluate` block and add your own code to wait for a DOM mutation or poll with `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` and effectively reimplement `waitForFunction` as fits your needs.

`waitForFunction` in particular is underused but it adds a huge amount of reliability and precision that `waitForTimeout` doesn't.

If all else fails and you have to block the script, you can delay, but I've written hundreds of Puppeteer scripts and have never had to use any sleep variant, so I'm pretty convinced it's basically unnecessary.

See [my blog post on Puppeteer Antipatterns](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout) for more analysis of why you should avoid sleeping in any form except as an absolute last resort.

See also the [Playwright docs for `waitForTimeout`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-timeout), which is essentially the same as the Puppeteer method:

> Discouraged
>
> Never wait for timeout in production. Tests that wait for time are inherently flaky. Use Locator actions and web assertions that wait automatically.

One caveat to the above: sleeping can be useful for temporary debugging while developing a script.

Comment: 100% agree with this line "waitForFunction in particular is underused but it adds a huge amount of reliability and precision that waitForTimeout doesn't."

Answer (score 4):

Try this function.

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

to use it

```
  async function demo() {
    console.log('Waiting...');
    await sleep(3000);
    console.log('ok');
  }

  demo();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
await new Promise(_func=> setTimeout(_func, 5000));
```

Comment: Many other answers already offer this with a clear explanation. Renaming `resolve` to `_func` is odd. Not only that, we really shouldn't be using this in Puppeteer anyway if we can possibly help it.