# Puppeteer how to retry url fetch with delay if it failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, es6-promise, puppeteer

I try to write simple web-**scraper** using [puppeteer library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer).

When I get page by url via `page.goto`, I need to retry if it failed, i.e response code is >= 400.

My snippet:

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 768});
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    await page.goto('https://google.com');

    await browser.close();
    process.exit();
})();
```

I need to implement fail strategy to retry url if `response.code` is >= 400.
I need delay beetween attempts equal to `retryNumber` * 1000ms:

- 1000 ms for first attempt;
- 2000 ms for second attempt;
- 3000 ms for third attempt and so on.

Promise should be rejected if `retryNumber` exceeds `maxRetryNumber`.

Who knows how to implement this via code? Are there any ready to use packets or snippets to achieve the goal?

Comment: https://github.com/zeit/async-retry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can then use a simple for loop to execute your retries (exit the for loop when your request was successful):

```js
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const delay = (ms) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 768});
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);

    const maxRetryNumber = 10;
    let success = false;
    for (let retryNumber = 1; retryNumber <= maxRetryNumber; retryNumber++) {
        const response = await page.goto('https://google.com');
        if (response.status() < 400) {
            success = true;
            break;
        }
        await delay(1000 * retryNumber);
    }

    if (!success) {
        // do something
    }

    await browser.close();
    process.exit();
})();
```

[Source of delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965281/8204697).

Comment: Thanks for pseudocode, it helped me to build real code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxRetryNumber = 10 ;
var retryNumber  = 0 ;

scrape();

async function scrape(){

    retryNumber++;
    if(retryNumber >= maxRetryNumber )
    {
        console.log(' retryNumber exceeded maxRetryNumber ! ');
        return ;
    }

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setViewport({width: 1024, height: 768});
        await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
        await page.waitFor(retryNumber*1000);
        let response = await page.goto('https://google.com');
        await browser.close();

        if(response.status()   >= 400)
            scrape();
        else
        {
            console.log('ALL OK');
        }
    }
    catch(e){

        scrape();

    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like recursive solutuion isn't the best approach in this case