# Puppeteer waitForTimeout is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in my latest project. I installed the library using NPM (`npm i puppeteer`). From the documentation I understood that the `page.waitFor()` function is now deprecated and replaced by `page.waitForTimeout()`.

When I try to use the new function I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: page.waitForTimeout is not a function`.

What could be the possible reason? The version of Puppeteer I got from NPM is 2.1.1.

Comment: "*The version of puppeteer I got from NPM is 2.1.1.*" – The latest version is 5.4.1. Either use the documentation for version 2.1.1 or upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: @str i thought that installing it from NP will get me the newest version. What is the way of updating? thank you

Comment: Not necessarily. Try `npm i puppeteer@latest`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`page.waitForTimeout` has been introduced in [puppeteer version `5.3.0`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/v5.3.0).

So as was mentioned in the comments, you can't use this new function in version `2.1.1` you had installed.

Bonus: [Issue #6214](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6214) contains more details to this topic.

Comment: Yes, if you are using old version  you can use `waitFor` for the newer version you have to use `waitForTimeout`

Comment: `waitForTimeout` was removed as of v22. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77078430/6243352) for details.

Answer (score 5):

Since old versions of Puppeteer don't include `waitForTimeout` and versions [>= 22](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/releases/tag/puppeteer-core-v22.0.0) removed the method, you can use a vanilla Node sleep:

```js
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";

// ...
await setTimeout(3000);
```

If you're on a super old version of Node that doesn't have `timers/promises`, you can always promisify `setTimeout` yourself, which is a nice pattern to be aware of since it works in the browser:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
})();
```

That said, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352) for an explanation of why sleeping should be avoided in general in Puppeteer, only used for temporary debugging, as an absolute last resort or in one-off hack scripts.