# Do you have to use waitForSelector before accessing it with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I've been working on a project that has a lot of tests that are very flakey. Often, a selector isn't found, so until now, our kludgey solution was to add manual delays here and there.

Previously, we had code like this:

```
const selector = 'my-selector';
const ele = await page.$(selector);
await ele.click();
```

I recently tried adding a `waitForSelector` before the `$` call like so:

```
const selector = 'my-selector';
await page.waitForSelector(selector);
const ele = await page.$(selector);
await ele.click();
```

It seems to be more reliable now. Is it basically essential to always use `page.waitForSelector()` before accessing an element`page.$()`? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not always necessary to use `waitForSelector`. If the element is already on the page, then just select it with `page.$`, `page.$eval`, etc, otherwise wait for it. If you're not sure whether it'll be there or not, best to wait for it.

`waitForSelector` is basically a common-case convenience wrapper on the more general `waitForFunction` which either registers a `requestAnimationFrame` loop or `MutationObserver` to wait for the callback predicate to be true. The [`waitForSelector` docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitforselector/) claim "If at the moment of calling the method the selector already exists, the method will return immediately" but I don't see that it runs a preliminary `page.$`-type query before attaching a `requestAnimationFrame` from the present code.

On the other hand, `page.$` and `page.$eval` and company simply run a `document.querySelector` for you with minimal overhead. Nonetheless, I wouldn't worry too much about performance; if you were to replace all `page.$` calls with `waitForSelector` calls, it'd probably not be super noticable.

On the other hand, I like the expressivity of using `page.$` when it's appropriate. It communicates intent that you're sure the element exists, not as clear if you use `waitForSelector` indiscriminately. `page.$` won't throw, so the reporting is weaker, probably pushing the throw to the next line (or further) when you try to access a property on `null`.

Note that `waitForSelector` [returns the first matching element](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#not-using-the-return-value-of-waitforselector-and-waitforxpath), so the code can be written as

```js
const selector = 'my-selector';
const ele = await page.waitForSelector(selector);
await ele.click();
```

Whatever you do, [don't sleep](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout). `waitForTimeout` is [being removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564) from the Puppeteer API, which is a good thing.

If you get tired of typing out `page.waitForSelector`, you can always write a little wrapper for it:

```js
const [page] = await browser.pages();
const $ = (...args) => page.waitForSelector(...args);
const foo = await $(".foo");
const bar = await $(".bar");
const baz = await $(".baz");
```

Comment: Ah, good point about my code being invalid - I was trying to simplify it for clarity, and did a bad copy-paste. Should I edit my post to correct it?

Comment: No problem--I figured as much. Please edit and I'll do the same.

Comment: Done - fixed my code example.