# How to get text inside frame with puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I want to extract the text result with the `"input#Readonly1"` selector. But unfortunately I get an empty text. (value contain an empty text)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var sleep = require('system-sleep');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub_FR/wmvpstv1_fr?SUBSESSIONID=16382865', { timeout: 8000 });

    const elementHandle = await page.$(
    'frame[name="AppWindow"]',);
  const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
  await frame.type("input[name='Writable3']", 'VF33C9HYB84113557', { delay: 5 });
  await frame.$eval("button[name='btnOphalen']", el => el.click());
  const element = await frame.waitForSelector("input#Readonly1", {visible: true}); // select the element
  const value = await element.evaluate(el => el.textContent);
  console.log(value);
  
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I think this line of code is incorrect:

```
const element = await frame.waitForSelector("input#Readonly1", {visible: true});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### There seem to be two errors:

1. The following line (as you mention in your question):

   ```
   const element = await frame.waitForSelector("input#Readonly1", {visible: true});
   ```

   Checking the page you're using, it seems that `input#Readonly1` is always visible, it only changes the value when you perform the query.

   ###### Updated taking into account [@ggorlen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6243352/ggorlen) answer and comments

   You can use [waitForFunction](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.frame.waitforfunction):

   ```
   await frame.click("button[name='btnOphalen']");
   await frame.waitForFunction(
     'document.querySelector("input#Readonly1").value.trim().length > 0',
     { polling: 'mutation' }
   );
   const element = await frame.$("input#Readonly1");
   ```

   ###### Why `{ polling: 'mutation' }`?

   According to [FrameWaitForFunctionOptions](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.framewaitforfunctionoptions):

   > - raf - to constantly execute pageFunction in requestAnimationFrame callback. This is the tightest polling mode which is suitable to observe styling changes.
   > - mutation - to execute pageFunction on every DOM mutation.
2. According to mdn: [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

   > For other node types, textContent returns the concatenation of the textContent of every child node, excluding comments and processing instructions. **(This is an empty string if the node has no children.)**

   Since you are retrieving the text inside an `input`, use `value` instead of `textContent`

   ```
   const value = await element.evaluate(el => el.value);
   ```

Comment: I tried with value instead of textContent but it didn't work

Comment: @Mohamedabdelmoula When viewing the page, you were right in the line that you indicate in your question as the wrong one, I update the answer there

Comment: thank you very much but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Mohamedabdelmoula I left the correct answer there, I got a bit confused with the puppeteer api, let me know if it still doesn't work

Comment: I added `await delay(1000);` after `await frame.$eval("button[name='btnOphalen']", el => el.click());` and it works. But I'm wondering if there isn't another way to not use delay ?

Comment: I tried `const element = await frame.waitForFunction('document.querySelector("input#Readonly1").innerText.includes(":")');` but it doesn't work

Comment: Since that page changes values using the api, the events (change, input, ...) are not emitted, so the only thing I can think of is to use a mutation observer, but I'm not really sure if it works.

Comment: Unless you don't want to use the delay function because of some design decision in your code, I think it's the cleanest solution.

Comment: Sleeping is not the cleanest solution, it was [removed from the Puppeteer API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352) for a reason. It is imprecise and either slows your script down for no reason or creates a possibility of failing when an unexpected delay arises. `waitForFunction` is better if you can find a predicate. I'll take a look here. Beyond that, though, the answer is correct about the `.value` issue and that there's no need to `waitForSelector` so it's helpful.

Comment: @Mohamedabdelmoula your `waitForFunction` can use `.value.includes()` and it should work, but you've probably already seen my solution. The issue with `:` is that maybe the format changes and `:` is no longer in the output, so I'd prefer a more general predicate like "wait for the value to change" or "wait until the contents are non-whitespace".

Comment: @ggorlen The sleep deprecation makes sense, checking around a bit, I was thinking of using `waitForResponse`, but using `waitForFunction` seems easier

Comment: `waitForResponse` is a good idea too, but the issue is that the response isn't a traditional JSON API response, so it seems easier to stick to working with the DOM.

Comment: @Mohamedabdelmoula and ggorlen thanks for the comments, there I updated the answer, tell me if there is something to correct 

Comment: Great update, thanks for not sleeping. Extremely minor point, but if a future version of the site does have some default non-space value in the input, the `waitForFunction` predicate here will fail, while my approach of "wait for _any_ change whatsoever" should still work. But it's highly unlikely--just a minor nitpick.

Answer (score 1):

The [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73920244/6243352) is correct that you would use `.value` rather than `.textContent` for getting the value from an input field. However, it also suggests a [sleep/delay workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564) in place of waiting for a proper predicate. Sleeping is inaccurate, resulting in either wasted time or false positives.

One better approach is using `waitForFunction` to compare the input's value before the click against its current value in a tight `requestAnimationFrame` loop. At the precise render that the value changes, the `waitForFunction` predicate will resolve and your code will continue on to the next line, taking no more or less time than it has to.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^18.0.4

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.mobilit.fgov.be/WebdivPub_FR/wmvpstv1_fr?SUBSESSIONID=16382865";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "load"});
  const el = await page.$('frame[name="AppWindow"]');
  const frame = await el.contentFrame();
  await frame.type("#Writable3", "VF33C9HYB84113557");
  const output = await frame.$("#Readonly1");
  const preValue = await output.evaluate(el => el.value);
  await frame.click("#btnOphalen");
  await frame.waitForFunction(preValue =>
    document.querySelector("#Readonly1").value !== preValue,
    {}, preValue
  );
  const value = await output.evaluate(el => el.value);
  console.log(value); // => Marque et type : PEUGEOT 307
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

To get all fields, try:

```js
await frame.$$eval('[id^="Readonly"]', els => els.map(el => el.value));
```