# nodejs using puppeteer, how to fix 'TypeError: browser.newpage is not a function'

Tags: node.js, bots, puppeteer

Below is the code which is trying to execute a browser going to the specified 'rand_url'.

Upon running the script I get the following errors:

```
TypeError: browser.newpage is not a function
    at initBrowser
    at async checkout
```

I am trying to figure out where I've gone wrong in trying to get this to execute in the browser.

Below is the .js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const rand_url = "URL Redacted for Privacy";

async function initBrowser(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newpage();
    await page.goto(rand_url);
    return page;
}

async function addToCart(page){
    //SELECT TICKET
    await page.$eval("button[class='btn btn-block button-primary ng-scope']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitfor(2000);
    //BRING UP ADD TO CART
    await page.$eval("button[class='buyer-type-minicart-button-container primary ng-scope']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitfor(2000);
    //ADD TO CART
    await page.$eval("button[class='primary block ng-scope']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitfor(2000);
    //CVV
    await page.type("input[id='input-one'", '630');
    await page.waitfor(2000);
    //CONFIRM AGE
    await page.$eval("button[class='data-protection-checkbox data-protection-opt-in-checkbox ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitfor(2000);
    //PLACE ORDER
    await page.$eval("button[class='btn button-primary ng-binding ng-scope']", elem => elem.click());
    await page.waitfor(2000);
}


async function checkout(){
    const page = await initBrowser();
    await addToCart(page);
}

checkout();
```

Comment: Please [see the docs](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browser.newpage). As an aside, [almost always avoid](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/06/14/puppeteer-in-nodejs-more-antipatterns-to-avoid.html#adding-premature-abstractions#using-attribute-css-syntax-for-classes) selectors like `button[class='btn button-primary ng-binding ng-scope']`. They'll fail if the order changes, or whitespace changes, or an extra class shows up in that class list. Prefer `.btn.button-primary.ng-binding.ng-scope` which ignores order and allows for extra classes to be present, and is more pleasant to read and type.

Comment: As another aside, [avoid timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352) which are unreliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that you have a typo in your method name. Try using
`browser.newPage` instead of `browser.newpage`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Usually, when it's just a typo, it's best to leave a comment and let those with close privileges remove the post. We have a close reason: "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo: While similar questions may be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers."

Comment: @ggorlen thanks for your comment. I will take it into account in the future

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is language where variable / function naming is usually in camelCase and variables and method names are case sensitive.

`browser.newpage()` and `browser.newPage()` are different calls.

Instance of browser has `newPage()` function, but doesn't have `newpage()`, so you get error that property `newpage` is not a function.

Same thing you have with `waitfor`. Page instance has `waitFor` (which is deprecated), in new Puppeteer versions this function is called `waitForTimeout`.

Also I suggest you not to use implicit waits and just to wait for selector and click on it.

Example:

```js
await page.waitForSelector("button[class='btn btn-block button-primary ng-scope']").then(el => el!.click());
```