# puppeteer web-automation and random scroll

Tags: scroll, puppeteer, webautomation

I am trying to automate a website traffic bot to gain higher rankings in google. It would search for my website in google, select from the results, go to website and scroll randomly up and down for a while then select a random internal link for up to about 3 or 4 pages. I would need it to perform a random scroll for each page.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require("fs");
const { scrollPageToBottom } = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down');


async function asyncCall() {

    // open a new browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

    // create a new page
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation();

    // navigate to google
    await page.goto('https://www.google.com');
    //await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 923 })


    // type slowly and parse the keyword
    await page.waitForSelector('#APjFqb');
    await page.click('#APjFqb');
    await page.type("*[name='q']", "krc seo tools", { delay: 500 });

    // Keyboard press
    await page.keyboard.press('Enter');

    //Navigate to Krc seo Tools
    await page.waitForTimeout(6_000);
    await navigationPromise

    await page.waitForSelector('.MjjYud:nth-child(1) > .g > .N54PNb > .kb0PBd > .yuRUbf > div > a > .LC20lb');
    await page.click('.MjjYud:nth-child(1) > .g > .N54PNb > .kb0PBd > .yuRUbf > div > a > .LC20lb');
    await page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    
    await navigationPromise

   // Page timeout
    await page.waitForTimeout(10_000);

    await browser.close();

}
asyncCall();
```

Comment: The second `await navigationPromise` does nothing here. Once a promise resolves, that's it, it will immediately return the already-resolved value (if any) on subsequent `await`s. Also, there's no navigation happening, so I'd expect this would probably just timeout. Your clicks and navigations [appear to be race conditions](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html). Using [long hardcoded chains of `>` is poor selector practice](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors).

Comment: [Timeouts in general should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352). See [this explanation](https://blog.appsignal.com/2023/02/08/puppeteer-in-nodejs-common-mistakes-to-avoid.html#making-unnecessary-calls-to-waitfornetworkidle-or-waitfornavigation) regarding excessive `waitForNavigation()`s (slightly different pattern shown, but the fundamental issue is the same). In any case, I don't see a question here or clarified any specific issue/error. What is the problem, exactly? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am trying to scroll through pages randomly, select an internal link, and also to have this done for 2 more pages like a loop.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do, but what's the problem with the code you showed here? Is there an error or some behavior you're dissatisfied with? If so, what specifically? There is no question being asked or specific issue raised, just a high-level goal and some code that presumably fails to achieve the stated goal with no explanation or question accompanying it.

Comment: LOL, I know it doesn't have any errors really but I would like some assistance with page scrolling up and down or random scrolling, and also to auto-select an internal link on my website. Any help would be greatly appreciated...