# How to click a random span element with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer, element, webautomation

I am trying to automate a bot to randomly select a tool/ link on my page "[KRC SEO TOOLS](https://www.krcinfo.com/)" with all the same span elements each time the page is been loaded or refreshed. I have tried so many ways but kept on failing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. kindly take a look at the image elements.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zArRe.jpg)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false, slowMo: 100, // Uncomment to visualize test
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Load "https://www.krcinfo.com/"
  await page.goto('https://www.krcinfo.com/');

  // Resize window to 1920 x 923
  //await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 923 });

  // Scroll wheel by X:0, Y:300
  await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(0, 300));

  // Click on a random link or tool
await page.waitForSelector('.tool_des')
  await Promise.all([
    page.click('.tool_des'),
    page.waitForNavigation()
  ]);

  await page.waitForTimeout(5_000)


  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: The code looks generally better than your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036386/puppeteer-web-automation-and-random-scroll) but same feedback here: what have you tried and what is your specific question here? If you want to pick a random element, you might start with `Math.random()`. To use `Math.random()` properly, you'll need to get an array of the elements: `const elements = await page.$$(".tool-des")`. After that, it's basically the same as [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/).

Comment: I have tried this before but it seems like I am not putting in the correct variables. hmm.  `await page.waitForSelector('.tool_des')` , `const elements = await page.$$(".tool-des")`, `const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length - 1);`  `await page.$(`.tool-des(${randomNumber}) a`).click()`

Comment: Cool, that's the right idea although I'd remove the `- 1` because that skips the last element, and then the query should be a bit different. Can you [edit] it into your post? I'll add an answer. Thanks.

Comment: hey man can you teach me coding lol.... am new to this.... I know these things comes at a price

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array) on an array of ElementHandles extracted with `page.$$`:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2

const url = "https://www.krcinfo.com/";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const els = await page.$$(".tool_des");
  const navP = page.waitForNavigation({waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  const i = Math.floor(Math.random() * els.length);
  await els[i].click();
  await navP;
  console.log(await page.url());
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

I'd be remiss not to mention that random numbers and nondeterminism aren't great things to introduce into tests, if that's what your use case is.