# How to fix issue that deprecated 'page.waitForTimeout' method usage

Tags: node.js, typescript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I made a web scraping script using the NodeJS Puppeteer package (v21.1.1) based on TypeScript.

I used `await page.waitForTimeout(3000);` method to delay the script running until page loading. This function works but it has the following issue:

```
The signature '(milliseconds: number): Promise<void>' of 'page.waitForTimeout' is deprecated.ts(6387)

types.d.ts(5724, 8): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.
```

I want to use an alternative instead of using a deprecated function.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution is not to use it, because arbitrary sleeps are slow and unreliable. Prefer event-driven predicates like `waitForSelector`, `waitForFunction`, `waitForResponse`, etc. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352) for details.

That said, if you *need* to sleep to help debug code temporarily, or you're writing a quick and dirty hack script which doesn't need to be reliable, just use a plain Node wait:

```js
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";

// ...
await setTimeout(3000);
```

Also possible is promisifying `setTimeout` yourself, which is useful if you're sleeping in the browser context:

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

(async () => {
  console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
  await sleep(3000);
  console.log(new Date().getSeconds());
})();
```

Comment: I fixed that issue using `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 3000))`. Thank you.