TypeError: waitForTimeout is not a function while running in puppeteer
I am trying to run a node.js puppeteer script that will search for a list of jobs in LinkedIn using the script below and will save the results in a text file.
However, I am Getting the following error:
PS C:\Users\Win10\puppeteer-project> node linkedin_job_search.js
Retrying after 1 attempts...
C:\Users\Win10\puppeteer-project\linkedin_job_search.js:34
        await page.waitForTimeout(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds
                   ^

TypeError: page.waitForTimeout is not a function
    at C:\Users\Win10\puppeteer-project\linkedin_job_search.js:34:20

I tried using both await waitForTimeout(10000), and await page.waitForTimeout(10000), still getting the same error.
Below is the code for the script.
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const { waitForTimeout } = require('puppeteer-core');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Navigate to LinkedIn login page
  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/login');

  // Enter your LinkedIn email and password
  await page.type('#username', 'email');
  await page. Type('#password', 'password');

  // Submit the login form
  let retries = 0;
  let maxRetries = 3;

  while (retries < maxRetries) {
    try {
      await Promise.all([
        page.click('.btn__primary--large'),
        page.waitForNavigation({
          waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
          timeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
        }),
      ]);
      break;
    } catch (error) {
      if (retries < maxRetries - 1) {
        retries++;
        console.log(`Retrying after ${retries} attempts...`);
        await setTimeout(10000); // Wait for 10 seconds
      } else {
        console.error('Failed to log in after ' + maxRetries + ' attempts. Exiting...');
        await browser.close();
        process.exit(1);
      }
    }
  }

  // Navigate to the jobs search page
  await page.goto('https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?keywords=Product%20Manager&location=India');

  // Wait for the search results to load
  await page.waitForSelector('.jobs-search-results__list');

  // Scrape the job listings
  const jobListings = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const listings = document.querySelectorAll('.jobs-search-results__list-item');
    return Array.from(listings).map((listing) => ({
      title: listing.querySelector('.job-card-list__title').textContent.trim(),
      company: listing.querySelector('.job-card-container__company-name').textContent.trim(),
      location: listing.querySelector('.job-card-container__metadata-item').textContent.trim(),
      link: `https://www.linkedin.com${listing.querySelector('.job-card-container__link').getAttribute('href')}`,
    }));
  });

  // Save the job listings to a text file
  const filePath = 'C:\Users\Win10\Documents\Python_Scripts\job_listings.txt';
  const fileContent = jobListings.map((job) => `Title: ${job.title}\nCompany: ${job.company}\nLocation: ${job.location}\nLink: ${job.link}\n\n`).join('');
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, fileContent);

  console.log(`Job listings saved to ${filePath}`);

  await browser.close();
})();`


Please post an error as text, not a screenshot.

@toyotaSupra just posted the error as text. Thank you.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77078345/how-to-fix-issue-that-deprecated-page-waitfortimeout-method-usage

Does this answer your question? How to fix issue that deprecated 'page.waitForTimeout' method usage

Try
await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10000))

instead. waitForTimeout doesn't work the way you think it does and puppeteer has removed page.waitForTimeout.
