# Unusual Puppeteer behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, headless

I am using Puppeteer to open a web browser headlessly to operate one website in JS. The website needs login before processing. So it opens a popup and closes it on login. I am trying to fill email and password in a popup through Puppeteer, to login. Sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it can't fill email.

I have tried various options. also, it works perfectly in the script. but the issue comes when I am accessing the script through API.

what can be the possible reason?

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });
global.__appRootDir = __dirname;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

const PORT = process.env.PORT ?? '3059'
const HOST = process.env.HOST ?? 'localhost';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('server is responding')
})

app.post('/conversion', conversion)

const conversion = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(process.env.SITE_URL, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

        await page.waitForSelector('button[id="login"]');
        await page.click('button[id="login"]');

        console.log("Popup Opened");

        const newPagePromise = new Promise(x => browser.once('targetcreated', target => x(target.page())));
        const popup = await newPagePromise;

        console.log("Find Inputs");
        const usernameInput = await popup.waitForSelector('input[id="username"]', { timeout: 30000 });
        await usernameInput.type(process.env.USERNAME)

        await popup.keyboard.press('Enter')

        const passwordInput = await popup.waitForSelector('input[id="password"]', { timeout: 30000 });
        await passwordInput.type(process.env.PASSWORD)

        console.log("Form  Filled");
        await popup.keyboard.press('Enter')

        // Create a promise that resolves when the popup page is closed
        const popupClosedPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            popup.once('close', () => {
                resolve()
            })
        })

        // Wait for the popup page to close
        await popupClosedPromise
        console.log("popup closed");

        console.log('login done')

        // next process - works perfectly.


    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
}

// listen for requests
app.listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
});
```

Site URL is: https://magicul.io/

Any username and password can be used to test. Here issue is, the username and password are not getting filled in the fields. you can use any text to test.

Sometimes, It's working perfectly, Sometimes, It stops after printing "Find Inputs".

Comment: Got it. One thing that looks weird, probably unrelated, is that `popupClosedPromise` isn't set before the action. I'd put the `await popup.keyboard.press('Enter')` after the listener, not before it. When you say 'It stops after printing "Find Inputs"', does a particular line time out? If so, which one exactly?

Comment: No nothing times out. the execution stops and nothing happens even after lot of waiting

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. That's strange, since all of those calls at that area are Playwright calls, all of which have a timer, so they're supposed to eventually throw an error. There's no call to `setDefaultTimeout(0)` anywhere that wasn't included, right?

Comment: No, this is all. no extra code.

Comment: I have added waitforselector for the image tag(logo) of the popup in the code today. will observe it for next 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set a time limit for waiting for this component? Try setting a timeout. You can use waitForSelector, waitForTimeout.
It could be that it's not appearing, or it could be that there's some treat that blocks it from being filled in and you have to wait a certain amount of time to try to run something on it.

Comment: [Timeouts are discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352)

Comment: @SaloniSaraiya Why isn't waitForSelector working as expected?