# Puppeteer testing - CdpElementHandle.click() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, mocha.js, puppeteer, chai

[image: Previous test finds the button but cannot click on it]I am trying to gain some basic understanding of how Puppeteer works and am struggling big time.
The app I am testing could be found [here](https://splendid-cannoli-3d964e.netlify.app).
Upon clicking on the Login button the app should redirect to Spotify and get AOuth authorization to search the API and create and save playlists in the logged-in user's account.
However, I do not think my test clicks on the button, although it "finds" it - it doesn't seem to do anything in `headless: false` mode and certainly does not redirect anywhere. the test fails of course too.
If I manage to resolve this problem one way or another, would I be able to get token in the "test mode" (sorry for the stupid expression, hopefully it is clear enough)? I cannot imagine being able to do this as Puppeteer will have to "log in" to Spotify but there must be a way.
As a side note could anybody please explain what expressions like `await page.waitForTimeout(HEADING_SELECTOR);` actually do. If I replace the argument with something meaningful, i.e. 10000 I am getting a timeout error. What does ***string value*** actually do?
Thanks.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const _ = require('lodash');
const globalVariables = _.pick(global, ['browser', 'expect']);


// puppeteer options
const opts = {
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 100,
    timeout: 10000
};

// expose variables
before(async function () {
    global.expect = expect;
    global.browser = await puppeteer.launch(opts);
});

// close browser and reset global variables
after(function () {
    browser.close();

    global.browser = globalVariables.browser;
    global.expect = globalVariables.expect;
});


describe('sample test', function () {

    // By default, Mocha tests have a 2 second timeout (which means that the test needs to be completed in 2 seconds).
    // You can increase it (in milliseconds) as follows:

    this.timeout(8000); // this test can take up to 5 seconds

    let page;

    before(async function () {
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('http://localhost:3000');
    });

    after(async function () {
        await page.close();
    })


    // TESTS
    it('should work', async function () {
        console.log(await browser.version());
        expect(true).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should have the correct page title', async function () {
        expect(await page.title()).to.eql('Spotify Playlist Creator');
    });

    it('should have correct heading', async function () {
        const HEADING_SELECTOR = 'h1';
        let heading;

        page.waitForSelector(HEADING_SELECTOR)

        /*
        page.$eval takes two arguments - selector and pageFunction. 
        It runs a document.querySelector in the browser environment and passes the result to the pageFunction. 
        Finally, it resolves with the value returned by pageFunction. 
        In this case, we are just returning the text for h1 tag.
        */
        heading = await page.$eval(HEADING_SELECTOR, heading => heading.innerText);

        expect(heading).to.eql('Spotify Playlist Creator');
    });

    it('should not display ErrorModal', async function () {
        const ERROR_MODAL_SELECTOR = '.ErrorModal';

        page.waitForSelector(ERROR_MODAL_SELECTOR)

        // The method runs document.querySelectorAll within the page. If no elements match the selector, the return value resolves to []
        expect(await page.$$(ERROR_MODAL_SELECTOR)).to.be.deep.equal([])
    });

    it('should be displaying login button', async function () {
        const LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR = 'button';
        let loginBtn;

        page.waitForSelector(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR);

        loginBtn = await page.$(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR)
        const btnText = await page.evaluate(loginBtn => loginBtn.textContent, loginBtn);

        expect(btnText).to.equal("Login to Spotify");
    });

    // DOES NOT WORK!!!
    it('should click login button', async function () {
        const LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR = 'button';
        let loginBtn;

        page.waitForSelector(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR);

        loginBtn = await page.$(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR)

        await loginBtn.click();
        console.log(loginBtn, "button has been clicked")

        expect(page.url()).to.include("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?");
    });
})
```

Comment: You need to `await loginBtn.click();`. Almost all Puppeteer API calls return promises and if you don't await them, you get race conditions and errors. `await page.waitForTimeout(HEADING_SELECTOR);` should fail. [`waitForTimeout`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfortimeout) accepts a number as its parameter, not a string. That said, timeouts are [not good to use in the first place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352). You probably want to use `waitForSelector` here. There may be other issues, but without a [mcve] it's hard to offer much than a quick spot check on sight.

Comment: Please update your code [as text, not a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). I'm still seeing missing `await`s in your code. Every Puppeteer call that returns a promise needs to be `await`ed. Missing an `await` is a non-starter.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. Of course page.waitForTimeout([string-value]) does not make sense. I was misled by an [old tutorial](https://ankit-m.github.io/blog/ui-testing-with-puppeteer-and-mocha/)
I have updated my original question by uploading a picture of the actual failing test. The previous test (finding the button) passes, the one where I click on the button and am expecting to be redirected to spotify's login page fails.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the desired effect with Cypress first:

```
cy.on("url:changed", (newUrl) => {
            expect(newUrl).to.contain([whatever-it-should-contain])
```

If I am not mistaken [Page.waitForNavigation() method](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.waitfornavigation) does the same in Puppeteer.
I am not a happy bunny as I wasted hours to figure this out - I never expected that a method called "waitForNavigation" waits for the page to navigate to a new URL... which of course is entirely my fault.
The correct test is below:

```
it.only('should click login button', async function () {
        const LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR = 'button';
        let loginBtn;
        page.waitForSelector(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR);
        loginBtn = await page.$(LOGIN_BUTTON_SELECTOR)

        await loginBtn.click();

        await page.waitForNavigation();
        expect(page.url()).to.include("https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?");
    });
```