# twiiter login using puppeteer not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, puppeteer

I am making a function for scrapping Twitter.
I need to login first and the do the rest of the work. but the problem is the login isnt working. Here is my code implementation. please help me out with this.

```js
static async verify_account(req, res, redis) {
        const { twitter_user, current_user } = req.body;
        const oldProxyUrl = 'http://user-default:XVIWM27mquqx@resi.proxiware.com:8080';
        const newProxyUrl = await proxyChain.anonymizeProxy(oldProxyUrl);
        
        
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: 'new',
            args: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                `--proxy-server=${newProxyUrl}`
            ]
        });

        let page;
        let totalAttempt = 0
        async function verify_twitter_account() {
            try {
                page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.goto("https://twitter.com/i/flow/login", { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 60000 });
                await page.evaluate(async() => {
                    await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
                           setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
                    });
                });
                // Select the user input
                await page.waitForSelector('[name="text"]', { timeout: 60000 });
                await page.type('input[name="text"]', twitter_user.useremail, { delay: 50 });
                

        
                // Press the Next button
                await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]')[2].click());
                await page.evaluate(async() => {
                    await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
                           setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
                    });
                });
                console.log('Started browser, entered email');
        
                const extractedText = await page.$eval("*", (el) => el.innerText);
        
                if (extractedText.includes("Enter your phone number or username")) {
                    await page.waitForSelector('input[autocomplete="on"]');
                    await page.type('input[autocomplete="on"]', twitter_user.username, { delay: 50 });
                    await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]')[1].click());
                    await page.waitForNetworkIdle({ idleTime: 1000 });
                console.log(`page if ${twitter_user.useremail}`, page.url());

                }
        
                await page.waitForSelector('input[autocomplete="current-password"]');
                await page.type('input[autocomplete="current-password"]', twitter_user.password, { delay: 50 });
        
                // Press the Login button
                await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelectorAll('div[role="button"]')[2].click());
                await page.evaluate(async() => {
                    await new Promise(function(resolve) { 
                           setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
                    });
                });
                console.log(`Login succeeded for ${twitter_user.useremail}`, page.url());
        
                if (page.url() === 'https://twitter.com/home') {
                console.log(`Login succeeded for ${twitter_user.useremail}`, page.url());
                    res.status(200).json({ result: true });
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({ result: false });
                }
        
                await browser.close();
                return true;
        
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error during login:', error);
                page && page.close();
                totalAttempt += 1;
        
                if (totalAttempt < 3) {
                    console.log('Retrying login...');
                    await verify_twitter_account();
                } else {
                    console.error('Max attempts reached. Login failed.');
                    res.status(200).json({ result: false });
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        

        await verify_twitter_account()
    }
```

The problem I am facing is its not proceeding to logged in state.
after login it should redirect to twitter home page. and in respose it should send true.

Comment: "Scrapping" Twitter is much easier (and probably better for you) than this; I think you mean "scraping".

Comment: `await page.evaluate(async() => { await new Promise(function(resolve) { setTimeout(resolve, 5000) }); });` does nothing without returning the promise, but why run this in the browser? `import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises"` then `await setTimeout(5000)` is the easier approach, or [avoid timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line) in favor of event-driven programming.