# Puppeteer click didn't work as expected for particular website

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to make puppeteer click on a button to get to a new UI. Clicking on this button in a regular browser works as expected, and so does using the chrome console in a real browser with `$('#DSOL_entryPage_generateBtn').click()`. But using puppeteer fails to proceed to the next screen using both `page.click()` as well as `page.evaluate()` methods. The screenshot shows that the page becomes empty as opposed to proceeding to the next screen:[image]

It is not clear whether the click itself is behaving differently, or the page's post-click behavior is different. But I verified it's not an issue with the screenshot, because await `page.waitForSelector('#inspirationInput');` will hang forever, meaning the next page was never reached.

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://myedit.online/en/audio-editor/ai-sound-effect-generator');
  // await page.click('#DSOL_entryPage_generateBtn');
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    document.querySelector('#DSOL_entryPage_generateBtn').click();
  });
  page.waitForTimeout(2000);
  // await page.waitForSelector('#inspirationInput');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'asdf.png' });

  await browser.close();
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with your resource - code  const url =
      "https://myedit.online/en/audio-editor/ai-sound-effect-generator";
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.click('#DSOL_entryPage_generateBtn');
    await page.waitForSelector('#inspirationInput');
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'asdf.png' });

works as expected and screenshot contain mentioned input

Comment: Works OK for me. `page.waitForTimeout(2000);` does nothing without an `await`. But `waitForNavigation()` or `waitForSelector` is [probably more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73676564/6243352), as Yaroslavm suggests above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you are not clicking button before the website is loaded

```
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
await page.waitForSelector(...)
```

If that haven't helped try using xpath selectors instead.