# Node.js Error: Node is either not clickable or is not an element

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm just learning to parse and I've encountered a problem. I probably misunderstood something or wrote something but I can't understand what it is

```
const puppeteer = require(`puppeteer`);

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false})
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.agsvyazi.ru/beeline/numbers/index.page.0.htm',{waitUntil: 'load'})

    let pages = 131;

    let idx = 0;

    const allPhns = [];

    while(pages > idx){

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        
        let arr = await page.evaluate(() => {

            let elem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.fl.number-table"), el => el.innerText)
            return elem
        })
        
        allPhns.push(...arr)

        // hrefPer = document.querySelector('div.listing a:last-child').href

        //await page.goto(document.querySelector('div.listing a:last-child').href)

        await page.goto(document.querySelector('div.listing a:last-child').href, {waitUntil: 'load'})

        idx +=1 
    }


    console.log(allPhns)

})()
```

I tried both page.goto and page.click . I searched a lot in the code of the element, tried querySelector() and querySelectorAll() different "paths". I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: I was expecting it to go to the next page (https://www.agsvyazi.ru/beeline/numbers/index.page.100.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a different error than you running your code:

```
script.js:30
        await page.goto(document.querySelector('div.listing a:last-child').href, {waitUntil: 'load'})
                        ^

ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

`document` doesn't exist in Node. It's only in the browser, which means you can only access it inside an `evaluate` callback:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.6.0

const base = "https://www.agsvyazi.ru/beeline/numbers/index.page.";

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
  await page.setRequestInterception(true);
  page.on("request", req =>
    req.url().startsWith(base) ? req.continue() : req.abort()
  );
  const data = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < 10 /* remove this to scrape everything */; i++) {
    try {
      const url = base + i * 100 + ".htm";
      console.log(url);
      await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
      const chunk = await page.$$eval(
        ".fl.number-table",
        els => els.map(e => e.textContent.trim())
      );
      data.push(chunk);
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(data);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Unless you're trying to throttle your requests, `await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));` is [not necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564). If you do need to sleep, a somewhat clearer way is using `import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";`.

---

Going a step further, if I understand correctly, I don't think you need Puppeteer for this, since the data is already in the static HTML. I'd suggest the built-in fetch along with the lightweight HTML parser Cheerio:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // ^1.0.0-rc.12

const base = "https://www.agsvyazi.ru/beeline/numbers/";

(async () => {
  let url = "index.page.100.htm";
  const data = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 10 /* remove this to scrape everything */; i++) {
    try {
      console.log(base + url);
      const res = await fetch(base + url);

      if (!res.ok) {
        break;
      }

      const $ = cheerio.load(await res.text());
      const chunk = [...$(".fl.number-table")].map(e =>
        $(e).text().trim()
      );
      data.push(chunk);
      url = $("div.listing a:last-child").attr("href");
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      break;
    }
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})();
```