# run a node js program from php works fine when run in terminal, but has no effect when triggered from browser

Tags: php, node.js, browser, puppeteer, node-modules

i have a node js program which uses puppeteer to take a SS of a webpage. i am calling this program from php code , when i run the php file from command line it executes the node js script successfully. but when it run the file on browser it neither throws any error nor executes the script.
Here is my mapCreate.php program

```
<?php
    $groupid = 89;
    echo "Hello";
    $groupName = "3DXLens";
    echo "Hello!!! " . get_current_user() . " + $groupName";
    $nodeScript = "nohup node /var/www/html/puppeteer-new/node.mjs 3DXLens  > /tmp/output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &";
    $output=shell_exec($nodeScript);
    echo $output;
    echo "Hello!!! after node call " . get_current_user() . " + $groupName";
?>
```

and here is my node.mjs

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
//const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
//const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
import sharp from 'sharp';
//const sharp = require('sharp');
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';

//puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
//const { executablePath } = require('puppeteer')
import  { executablePath }  from 'puppeteer';
puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'], executablePath: executablePath() }).then(async browser => {
    console.log('Running tests..');
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Retrieve HOST_NAME from command-line arguments
    const HOST_NAME = process.argv[2];
    // process.argv[0] is the path to node, process.argv[1] is the path to the script

    // Check if HOST_NAME is provided
    if (!HOST_NAME) {
        console.error('HOST_NAME is not provided.');
        process.exit(1); // Exit the script with an error code
    }

    // Set a large viewport size
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

    await page.goto('https://monitoring.minutuscloud.com/zabbix/');
    await page.type('#name', 'Admin');
    await page.type('#password', 'zabb!x@Minutus');
    await page.click('[type=submit]');
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await page.click('.icon-monitoring');
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const mapsLink = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(a => a.textContent.includes('Maps'));
        mapsLink.click();
    });
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

    // Use HOST_NAME within page.evaluate()
    await page.evaluate((HOST_NAME) => {
        const mapLink = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a')).find(a => a.textContent.includes(HOST_NAME));
        if (mapLink) { // Check if mapLink is found before clicking
            mapLink.click();
        } else {
            console.error('Map link not found.');
        }
    }, HOST_NAME);
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000)
    // Scroll to the bottom of the page
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    });
    await page.waitForTimeout(2000);

    // Capture a full-page screenshot
    await page.screenshot({ path: '/tmp/testresult.png', fullPage: true });

    await browser.close();
    sharp('/tmp/testresult.png')
        .extract({ left: 200, top: 80, width: 1700, height: 800 })
        .toFile('/tmp/test-new.jpg', function (err) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        })
    console.log(`All done, check the screenshot. ✨`);
});
```

when i run php mapCreate.php from command line on the same machine where the code is it works fine and does all the taks. it creates the screenshots, but when i run it in browser directlt it only displays HelloHello!!! root + 3DXLensHello!!! after node call root + 3DXLens
there are no errors, i had a js file instead of node.mjs where there were require statements(commented one's) instead of import. Even that had same behaviour.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a problem of PHP or of Node?

Comment: Also, please be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: will work on sql injection thing. the problem looks with node, my other php and shell scripts are working fine. the mapcreate.php is getting executed. but the node js one is not. not able to figure out why. works perfect from command line

Comment: I suggest minimizing the problem further. A lot of the code here makes the problem not reproducible and probably isn't relevant, like the database work. Just hardcode in whatever data the db queries are returning, and either hardcode, avoid or provide the other shell scripts. See [mcve] for guidance. As for Puppeteer and PHP, [avoid sleeping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919013/puppeteer-wait-n-seconds-before-continuing-to-the-next-line/73676564#73676564).

Comment: sure, here is the simplified php code ```<?php
    $groupid = 89;
    echo "Hello";
    $groupName = "3DXLens";
    echo "Hello!!! " . get_current_user() . " + $groupName";
    $nodeScript = "nohup node /var/www/html/puppeteer-new/node.mjs 3DXLens  > /tmp/output.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &";
    $output=shell_exec($nodeScript);
    echo $output;
    echo "Hello!!! after node call " . get_current_user() . " + $groupName";
?>
``` still i face the same problem, when i run php from the command line using php mapcreate.php it works, but when i run it on browser it does nothing but prints echo

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase done. i am able to run the puppeteer script from php file from command line, but from browser it doesn't work